# list item click event not firing when parent div set to hidden after click event in anglar application

Tags: angular, events

I am working on an angular project: Angular 8.2.12 Angular-Cli: 8.3.14

The following simple clickable ul listing is not firing its click event if its parent div is set to hidden after the click event (i.e. the `div` will present the items first as a visible list, then right after user clicks on an item, it will set the `div` to be hidden):

```
<div [hidden]="!visiblecond">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let itm of items"
        (click)="onClick($event)">
        {{ itm.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the component:

```
onClick($event) {
  console.log("clicked");
}
```

The `(click)` event is not firing. BUT, if i get rid of the `[hidden]` property binding on the containing `div` (i.e. the item listing is visible at all time), it will fire the click events!

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set `visiblecond`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div`'s `visiblecond` is set by a text input field's focus (true) and blur (false) events, so, whenever I click to select an item on the item list, it is outside of the text input field, apparently, the text field's blur event "masks" the item's click event, causing it to not fire. So I just rid of the blur event, and the item's click event is firing